# How would I exclude query results if the result has a timestamp within a particular range of another result?

Tags: sql

Let's say I have the following results

```
Person   Action   Item    Time 
Jane     Ate      Apple   2015-10-27 18:52:22 
Jane     Ate      Apple   2015-10-27 18:53:18
Jane     Ate      Apple   2015-10-28 5:16:45
```

I want to first two Jane results to be consolidated and only appear once because they happened on the same day... Essentially looking for the MAX time per day and not the MAX time in general.

Comment: Essentially my results are within minutes of one another and I only want to max, but don't want to discard results for the next day by using a max function.

Comment: Which database system are you using?  There are a couple different options depending...

Comment: Good question @sgeddes. I am using Microsoft SWL Server Management Studio. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `row_number` to select the action per person per item per day with the max time:

```
select * from (
  select row_number() over (partition by person, action, item, CONVERT(date, time) order by time desc) rn, *
  from mytable
) t1 where rn = 1
```

Comment: This won't return the max(time) per day, only the distinct date.  Depending on the OP needs, it could work though...

Comment: @fuzzytree thank you so much! Can you elaborate? When you say select the date portion of my datetime field, do you mean simply adding DATE() in front of the column I am trying to pull data from? If so, It looks like I may not have that as a "recognized built -in function name".

Comment: @sgeddes you articulated that so well. That is exactly what I need. The max time per day!

Comment: @sgeddes thanks, I misunderstood the question. see update

Comment: @sgeddes A huge thanks to you as well. I am very grateful!!

Answer (score 2):

I think you want to `group by` and use `max` as your aggregate function. Something like this:

```
select person, action, item, max(time)
from mytable
group by person, action, item, convert(date, time)
```